# sql appending data from other table to current table with conditions

Tags: sql, insert, append, select-into

I have 2 tables, `PRODUCT` and `VENDOR`. The attributes for each are as follows:

```
PRODUCT: product_id, product_name, price, vendor_id

VENDOR: vendor_id, vendor_name, vendor_phone, vendor_address
```

I want vendor_name to show in PRODUCT where `vendor_id` in `PRODUCT` matches `vendor_id` in `VENDOR` **without creating a view**. I've looked into SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO, but I may be doing it wrong. I'm also doing this in Access as it's just dummy data for a classroom module.

Comment: Select into and Insert into are vastly different things. I don't either of these is at all what you want. Select into will create a new table and inset into will add rows to an existing table. I would STRONGLY advise not to denormalize your data like that. Keep those tables separate and create a query to return the values you want to see.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. How do developers usually do it though. I'm a business analyst and I see that in our company's database, `vend_id` and `vend_name` in the `PRODUCT` table matches the values in the `VENDOR` table.

Comment: Ugh vend_name should NOT be in the Product table. vend_id is the only vendor data that should be there. That is the foreign key. The rest of the data should come from the vendor table. In your original post I don't see vendor_name in the product table.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample above I would write your query something like this.

```
    select product_id
    , product_name
    , price
    , vendor_name
    , vendor_phone
    , vendor_address
from Product p
inner join vendor v on v.vendor_id = p.v.vendor_id
```